# How to filter by one or more older ages

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to show older people. Condition: if there is more than one person of the same age, must show all people tied.

Sample input:

```
John   19
Zach   45
Rose   22
Kate   45
```

Output should be:

```
Older person or people: [Zach, Kate]
```

Any help would genuinely be appreciated. Thanks!

Domain class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private static List<String> olderPeople = new ArrayList<>();

    public Person(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static String getOlderPeople() {
        return Arrays.toString(olderPeople.toArray());
    }

    public int compareTo(Person person) {
        int result = age.compareTo(person.age);
        if (result == 0) {
            olderPeople.add(person.name);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestPerson {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("John", 19));
        persons.add(new Person("Zach", 45));
        persons.add(new Person("Rose", 22));
        persons.add(new Person("Kate", 45));

        System.out.println("Older person or people: " + Person.getOlderPeople());
    }
}
```

Comment: Help with what? What have you tried?

Comment: `olderPeople` list seems to just complicate your case. You should just operate on `persons` list.

Comment: Easiest way find max age first iterate using loop then iterate again to find out person of that age and add in a new list

Comment: When I run the array is empty []
There is something that is not right here, but I don't know what it is

Comment: You are never actually adding anything to the `olderPeople` list

Comment: @eric556 I'm trying to add to the orderPeople list in the compareTo method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Stream API

```
List<Person> person = persons.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getAge(), TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
        .lastEntry().getValue();
```

Here collect as group and map to TreeMap and get the last entry's value means max aged list

And use your compare function like since you just want to compare age

```
public int compareTo(Person person) {
    return age.compareTo(person.age);
}
```

Comment: Good note on the Comparable contract, I just noticed this myself.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is find the max and then check if any others match that max. If this is possible with a single Stream let me know! Would definitely be cool.

```java
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                new Person("John", 19), new Person("Zach", 45),
                new Person("Rose", 22), new Person("Kate", 45));

        Person oldest = persons.stream()
                .max(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge))
                .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);

        List<Person> allOld = persons.stream()
                .filter(person -> person.getAge().intValue() == oldest.getAge().intValue())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Regarding Comparable
You `shouldn't` be comparing the contents of the internal list stored in Person. You actually `shouldn't` store that list in your domain. Instead, when you `compare` two objects you should really only be comparing those two domains and nothing else. That being said, `Integer#compare(int, int)` properly implements this contract and will return the larger number.

```java
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Person o) {
            return Integer.compare(age, o.age);
        }
```

Comment: I used your code and it showed a compilation error in the ".max ()" method ... What can it be?

"The method max(Comparator<? super Person>) in the type Stream<Person> is not applicable for the arguments ()"

Comment: One moment, my apologies, i'll fix.

Comment: Edited, try that.

Comment: Hey buddy, I tried again and only returned the last result "Kate", it must be the filter

Comment: Oops the age of Kate is 145, not 45, haha.

Comment: Now I get it haha